# How to add a confirm button handler

Tags: sweetalert2

is there a way to add a handler to the confirm button (so that I can clear the error message when the user clicks confirm) :

`````
{ magic.errorMessage && <SweetAlert
              title="Error"
              show={true}
              html={magic.errorMessage}
              type="error"
              showCancelButton={false}
              showConfirmButton={true}
              onClick={() => { console.log("YES YES YES") }}
              
            />
          }````
`````

Comment: for the record I originally was using `show={magic.errorMessage}` but that was leading to react dom render issues

Answer (score 0):

```
<SweetAlert
              title="Error"
              show={!magic.entity?.loggedIn && magic.errorMessage}
              html={magic.errorMessage}
              type="error"
              showCancelButton={false}
              showConfirmButton={true}
              onConfirm={() => clearError()}
            />
```